# unsupported locale %tts = default:%tts

Tags: text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech, tasker

This task on Tasker is supposed to say the hour time out loud, but it gives this error:

```
22.07.47/Variables doreplresult: |%hour| -> |23|
22.07.47/Variables doreplresult: |%tts| -> |%tts|
22.07.47/E onUtteranceCompleted: Say: .speechStart id: null err: false
22.07.47/E Say:  engine: default locale data: %tts default engine: true
22.07.47/E set TTSStatus to -34234 by doSpeech: init
22.07.47/E Say: start init loop
22.07.47/E Say: oof: status; 0 elapsed: 150
22.07.47/E Say: tts engine: default voice data: %tts loclang: %tts
22.07.47/E tts: loc %tts available: -2
22.07.47/E TTS: unsupported locale %tts = default:%tts.
22.07.47/E Say: not started, shutdown
22.07.47/E result: stop task (error)
22.07.47/E Error: 1
22.07.47/MacroEdit action finished exeID 1 action no 9 code 559 status: Err next 9
```

How to fix this? Google TTS is already installed, with proper languages. The variable `%tts` is set to `com.google.android.tts:deu-deu`.

Comment: `%tts = default:en` ?

Comment: @brandall The variable `%tts` is set to `com.google.android.tts:deu-deu`. But now it works again, I don't know why.